# When to use type="other" in the survey package of R?

Tags: r, survey

I have computed replicate weights using the survey package in R. These weights are calculated using the jackknife method (specifically the JKN method). Each of these replicates are then adjusted for nonresponse (using response propensity adjustment), raked and then expanded. Now, I have my final replicate weights. I would like to create a survey design using these weights. Here is my codes:

```
# define  final survey design
jkn.rep.dsgn <- svrepdesign(data = data[,c(1:110)],
                           repweights = data[,1092:2071],
                           type = "JKn",
                           weights = data$exp_weight,
                           combined.weights = TRUE,
                           scale = 1,
                           rscales = 1)
```

Now, I am a bit confuse on what I should use as type? Shall I use "JKn" because this is what I used to calculate base replicate weights? or "others" since I already made adjustments with the replicate weights?

Thank you!

Comment: could you provide more detail about the survey data set you're using?  is it public microdata (and possibly documented on asdfree.com)?

Comment: Hello anthony! no, it is not a public data. It is a household travel survey done privately for a particularly city in US. The survey was a stratified random sampling where respondents are selected with unequal probability. It is a single stage. The computation of the final weights makes it complicated though thats why I opted to use jackknife to estimate the standard errors. By the way, been checking your site too before I posted my question. Thanks for providing all the infos :)

Comment: i compared the standard errors for both types and its actually the same. Im not sure if this is true for all or it is just by chance.